# How to find the caller of these JS files?

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have a file called `index.html` that is supposedly display a map by executing this line : `Controller.startup(notauth);`. I have made sure that the logic comes to this line.
Somehow the map wont appear and i find out in the Chrome debugger that there are some calls to a wrong JS scripts path.

Here I include some lines from my `index.html` :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            packages: [{
                name: 'viewer',
                location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'js/viewer'
            },{
                name: 'config',
                location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'js/config'
            },{
                name: 'gis',
                location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'js/gis'
            }]
        };


    </script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.255.1.77/sonar/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/3.15/init.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">             
            //Get app ID from url 
            var file = 'config/viewer', s = window.location.search, q = s.match(/config=([^&]*)/i);
            //alert ('var file ORI (config/viewer) : ' + file);
            //alert ('nilainya Q : ' + q);
            if (q && q.length > 0) {
                file = q[1];
                //alert ('Q1 : ' + file);
                //alert ('S : ' + s);
                if(file.indexOf('/') < 0) {
                        configfile = 'config/' + file;
                }
                //alert ('CONFIG-FILE : ' + configfile);
            }

if (configfile == 'config/all') 
            {

                //alert ('config == ALL');
                //alert ('configfile is ' + configfile + ' -- strpathfile  : ' + strpathfile);


                if (ImgStatus && checkfileimg_js(strpathfile)) {
                    require(['viewer/Controller', configfile + '_imagery'], function(Controller, config){
                    Controller.startup(config);
                    });
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    alert ('controller.startup(notauth) Hellow NOAUTH ');
                    require(['viewer/Controller', 'config/all'], function(Controller, notauth)
                        {
                        Controller.startup(notauth);
                        });
                    }   
            }               
                else    //IF configfile <> ALL (env,pims,clear dll)

            { 
                Controller.startup(auth);
            }
```

When i debug it in Chrome, I have the following results :
- result 1 : https://snag.gy/g37joA.jpg
- result 1 : https://snag.gy/aBMren.jpg

The correct path should be "http://10.255.1.77/sonar/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/3.15/dijit/TitlePane.js"
NOT http://10.255.1.77/sonar/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/dijit/TitlePane.js

Where are those JS coming from ? I cant find them being called in my index.html. Where and how can i find lines that calls these JS scripts ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information in **Chrome DevTools**, tab `Network`, column `Initiator`:

[image: Initiator column in Chrome DevTools]

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure correctly the `HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI`  in your `init.js` and `dojo.js` (inside esri js api),

should look like in both `init.js` and  :

`http://10.255.1.77/sonar/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/3.15/`

> Where are those JS coming from ?

The scripts are laoded asynchronously ( see [Modern dojo AMD](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) )

```
 require(['viewer/Controller'], function(controller)) ...
```

this will search for viewer (depends on config dojo created on top)`your_app_url/js/viewer/Controller.js` and load it in script and register it ,

also every require inside your controller will load scripts asynchronously , this modern AMD will prevent import unused modules (modular loading) .

Comment: @padjee does it make sences ?

Comment: yes it makes sense... I know its happening in init.js but i don't know what causes it. I just cant find out the exact error location caused by init.JS calling the wrong path. Finally and luckily, I find it by accidents by changing the HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI to the correct one. I should have put http://10.255.1.77/sonar/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/3.15/dojo instead of http://10.255.1.77/sonar/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/3.15/

Comment: yeah depends on folder located this last !